# Cannot start bundle programmatically

Tags: osgi, osgi-bundle, embedded-osgi

**Note**: In my case, I'm using `Apache Felix` implementation if that's matters.

I have written bundle which I'm using as test. It's very simple "Hello World" bundle that do nothing more than print message to `stdout` when started/stopped:

```
public class Activator implements BundleActivator {

    @Override
    public void start(BundleContext context) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Hello, World.");
    }

    @Override
    public void stop(BundleContext context) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Goodbye, World.");
    }

}
```

There is also `MANIFEST` file which rather pointless to post since when I deploy above bundle through `Apache Felix` console from standard distribution ([which can be downloaded here](http://ftp.ps.pl/pub/apache//felix/org.apache.felix.main.distribution-5.6.4.tar.gz)) bundle starts and print out message.

---

Next step I'm trying to do is deploy the very same bundle using programmatic approach. Unfortunately this is not working for me. My code looks as follow:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    FrameworkFactory frameworkFactory = getFrameworkFactory();
    Framework framework = frameworkFactory.newFramework(null);

    System.out.println("BundleID = " + framework.getBundleId());
    System.out.println("State = " + getState(framework.getState()));

    framework.init();

    System.out.println("BundleID = " + framework.getBundleId());
    System.out.println("State = " + getState(framework.getState()));

    BundleContext bundleContext = framework.getBundleContext();
    bundleContext.addBundleListener((event) -> {
        System.out.println("Bundle Changed Event");
    });
    bundleContext.addFrameworkListener((event) -> {
        System.out.println("Framework Event");
    });
    bundleContext.addServiceListener((event) -> {
        System.out.println("Service Changed Event");
    });

    Bundle bundle = bundleContext.installBundle("file://<absolute-path-to-bundle-jar-same-as-above");

    System.out.println("BundleID = " + bundle.getBundleId());
    System.out.println("State = " + getState(bundle.getState()));

    bundle.start();

    System.out.println("BundleID = " + bundle.getBundleId());
    System.out.println("State = " + getState(bundle.getState()));
}

private static FrameworkFactory getFrameworkFactory() throws IllegalStateException {
    ServiceLoader<FrameworkFactory> loader = ServiceLoader.load(FrameworkFactory.class);

    FrameworkFactory factory = null;
    for (FrameworkFactory iterator : loader) {
        if (factory != null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Ambiguous SPI implementations.");
        }

        factory = iterator;
    }

    return factory;
}

private static String getState(int state) {
    switch (state) {
    case Bundle.UNINSTALLED:
        return "UNINSTALLED";
    case Bundle.INSTALLED:
        return "INSTALLED";
    case Bundle.RESOLVED:
        return "RESOLVED";
    case Bundle.STARTING:
        return "STARTING";
    case Bundle.STOPPING:
        return "STOPPING";
    case Bundle.ACTIVE:
        return "ACTIVE";
    default:
        throw new IllegalStateException("Unknown state");
    }
}
```

The output looks like follow:

```
BundleID = 0
State = INSTALLED
BundleID = 0
State = STARTING
Bundle Changed Event
BundleID = 1
State = INSTALLED
BundleID = 1
State = INSTALLED
```

So as far as I understand bundle got installed but last 4 lines indicate that `bundle.start()` got ignored for some reason.

Could you point out me what am I missing to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

After hour of debugging and reading through `javadoc` more carefully this is happening because framework was only initialized instead of being started. To make example work you have to simply  add `framework.start()` after `framework.init()` (or just call `framwork.start()` which calls `framework.init()` if found it necessary).

I'm leaving this information as there are few confusing things:

1. Official documentation to `Apache Felix` have information about embedding framework into host application. Unfortunately there is only example that use `Apache Felix` custom mechanisms that make it not portable to other implementations. What is confusing is [warning note](http://felix.apache.org/documentation/subprojects/apache-felix-framework/apache-felix-framework-launching-and-embedding.html#embedding-the-felix-framework) which if you want to create portable solution you should use `init()` and `getBundleContext()`. Whole note cited bellow:

> **WARNING** The `felix.systembundle.activators` configuration property is specific to the Felix framework implementation. If you want your code to work with other framework implementations, you should call `init()` on the framework instance and use `getBundleContext()` directly. Otherwise, the approach would be very similar.

2. JavaDoc for parameterless version of `init()` method do not mention about initialization is not same as starting the framework, although `init(FrameworkListener...)` have such information.

> This Framework will not actually be started until start is called.